# Merge sort using two recursive functions rather than one recursive and one iterative

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I've tried to use divide and conquer to create a merge sort algorithm. It is made up of a mergesort recursive function which I'm confident is correct but within it it calls a merge function, which is also recursive but isn't working. So I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this so that it works. I've seen the other solutions for defining merge using while loops etc and I get the idea there but I want to see if the merge function can be written recursively instead.

At the moment the when I implement the code I just get an empty array which is frustrating.

```
def mergesort(A):
    length_A = len(A)
    if length_A > 1:
        return merge(
            mergesort(A[0:length_A//2]),
            mergesort(A[length_A//2 + 1:length_A-1]))
    else:
        return A

def merge(x,y):
    length_x = len(x)
    length_y = len(y)
    if length_x == 0:
        return x
    if length_y == 0:
        return y

    if x[0] <= y[0]:
        return x[0] + merge(x[1:length_x -1],y[0:length_y -1])
    else:
        return y[0] + merge(x[0:length_x-1],y[1:length_y -1])

A = [10, 2, 5, 3, 7, 13, 1, 6]
a = mergesort(A)
print(a)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wonky,please fix.

Comment: You don’t need the backslash for line continuation when you are within parentheses.

Comment: The recursive merge will work, but it will require O(n) stack space to merge n nodes, which could result in stack overflow for a large list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

In the merge, if one of the lists to be merged is empty, you don't want to return *that* list, you want to return the other because this is the one with the remaining values. In other words, this is backward:

```
if length_x == 0:
    return x

if length_y == 0:
    return y
```

It should be:

```
if length_x == 0:
    return y

if length_y == 0:
    return x
```

Also you are trying to concat ints and lists with this:

```
# x[0] is a number
return x[0] + merge(x[1:length_x -1],y[0:length_y -1])
```

Something like this might be a little better:

```
def mergesort(A):
    length_A = len(A)
    split = length_A // 2

    if length_A > 1:
        return merge(mergesort(A[0:split]), mergesort(A[split:]))
    else:
        return A


def merge(x,y):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return y

    if len(y) == 0:
        return x

    if x[0] <= y[0]:
        return [x[0]] + merge(x[1:], y)
    else:
        return [y[0]] + merge(x, y[1:])


A = [10,2,5,3,7,13,1,6]
a = mergesort(A)
print(a)
```

**result**

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 13]
```